# codenameone Title bar text doesn't show

Tags: codenameone

Everything was fine, when my cn1 projects automatically downloaded new libs on 21 May 2016 at 10 : 00 the titles text disappeared. This degraded my apps.

The title show on the GUI builder but on the simulator and IOS device nothing shows on the title bar.

can someone help.

on GUI Builder :

[image]

on Simulator and device :

[image]

This was just fine before. How can i remove the last automatic update ?

Comment: Only down votes ?!!! my app was working fine for over a month now, and today this happens with no changes made what so ever. and i m asking @Shai if i m wrong.

Comment: here is the answer my down voting friends, something changed in the new libs so now i had to define the title manually instead of via GUI builder :                                                                                          f.setToolbar(new Toolbar());
f.setTitle("Paramètrage");
f.getToolbar().addCommandToLeftBar("  Retour", null, actionBack);
f.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar("OK  ", null, actionSave);

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that is a question is unclear to someone they assume it's unclear to everyone, it seems phrased correctly and I don't see the reason for the downvotes other than some overzealous moderators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We made some changes to back button behavior in the Toolbar with the latest update which might have triggered this. Try overriding this in the state machine and see if it helps:

```
protected void setBackCommand(Form f, Command backCommand) {
    if(shouldAddBackCommandToMenu()) {
        f.addCommand(backCommand, f.getCommandCount());
    }
    f.setBackCommand(backCommand);
}
```